# Need help in creating a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with below data.

```
columnA  columnB
ONE      value 1
ONE      value 2
ONE      value 3
TWO      value 1
TWO      value 2
THREE    value 1
```

Need help in creating a query which gives below

```
COLUMN X   COLUMN Y
ONE         value 1, value 2, value 3
TWO         value 1, value 2
THREE       value 1
```

Comment: To get help writing a query, check out [this Q&A](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: Also, please specify your version of SQL Server, as the options are different for different versions.

Answer (score 6):

What you are needing help is called [Grouped Concatenation in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation)

This [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc77f/6) that I created will help you.

Basically you use stuff + FOR XML PATH.

If you are on sql server 2017 (vNEXT) then [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is an inbuilt function that you can use

-- sql server vNEXT

```
SELECT [ColumnA]  =  [ColumnA],
       [ColumnBs] = STRING_AGG(ColumnB, ',')
 from dbo.Table1   
 group by ColumnA
```

Comment: `Case when row_number() over (order by columnb) = 1 then '' else ',' end + columnB` is more understandable than stuff. Or use lag/lead if you want to do different things for the first and last.